# Crystal Report showing Poor quality Text Preview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019

I am using Crystal report v13.0.4000.0 in my windows forms application in VS2019.

**My Problem**: Crystal report preview shows Pixelated poor-quality text at runtime. I'm wondering is it just like that OR is there any workaround for that. I have seen SSRS and RDLC
they show crystal clear text in the preview at runtime. Here are images for comparison:

**Picture 1** : Preview at runtime
[image]

**Picture 2** : Preview when viewing Crystal report viewer in VS2019 !
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMIQ8.png)

Both images are from the same VS2019 Project.
If anybody knows about this or even has an idea please share your thoughts.

**Note** : Above images contain truly Text Field. Printer report is Crisp and clear the problem is with the preview only why cant I get picture 2nd image quality in the preview.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal renders content to the screen based on the capabilities of the default (or specified printer).
So Make sure the default/specified printer is capable, and that the printer driver is patched/recent.

Comment: Output printer report is fine and clear the problem is with the preview only why cant i get picture 2nd image quality in the preview.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify: are these truly text or are they images you are displaying inside Crystal?
If they are images, test the effect of setting the viewer's property of ***InterpolationMode*** to ***Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic***

Comment: Yes, they are truly Text. The property You've mentioned is not working it has to do with image quality. How can make Text more clear as in the 2nd image ?

Comment: As indicated in my answer, that property applies only to images.
AFAIK, text resolution can be impacted only by the printer driver.

Comment: text quality on the page is good. but what about the preview quality? I have seen other software which uses older version of CR though the preview quality is clear & good than my current version of CR.